# How to switch user from i3lock?

Tags: lubuntu, lock-screen, i3-wm

On most lock screens, there's a "Switch User" button.  However, i3lock doesn't seem to have any buttons.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch user or an option to add a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. i3lock is minimalist. See the man page http://linux.die.net/man/1/i3lock

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LightDM greeter as locking screen:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

You can switch between users there.

Comment: Doesn't work with gdm, i.e. with 18.04 (out of the box).